# Excel VBA: Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I have a macro in excel which loops over the tabs and saves the tabs as PDFs in a given folder.

The macro partially works, it creates a few PDFs but then stops and throws this error:

```
Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument
```

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim strTime As String
Dim strName As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim rng As Range

' Prevents screen refreshing.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook

strPath = wbA.Path
strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")

'get active workbook folder, if saved
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"

' Begin the loop.
For Each wsA In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
    strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
    strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

    If strName = "Macro" Then
        MsgBox "That's all folks! :)"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If strName = "TOUCHPOINTS" Then
        strName = "Touchpoints by markets"
    End If

    If strName = "VIDEOHOURS" Then
        strName = "Viewing Hours by markets"
    End If

    If strName = "TARGETS" Then
        strName = "Shares by markets"
    End If

    If strName = "SHARESCHANNELS" Then
        strName = "IGNORE ME"
    End If

    If strName = "TOP10PREMIERES" Then
        strName = "Top 10 Premieres by markets"
    End If

    If strName = "SHARETREND" Then
        strName = "Share trends last 13 months"
    End If

    If strName = "COMPETITION" Then
        strName = "Share overview international media companies"
    End If

    If strName = "COMPETITIONSHARETREND" Then
        strName = "Share trends factual competitors last 13 months"
    End If

    If strName = "PUT" Then
        strName = "PUT level"
    End If

    If strName = "CHANNELRANKER" Then
        strName = "Top 20 Channels by Market"
    End If

    'create default name for savng file
    strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
    myFile = strPath & strFile

    Debug.Print myFile

    'export to PDF if a folder was selected
    If myFile <> "False" Then
        wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:=myFile, _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If

Next wsA

 ' Enables screen refreshing.
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So where do you get the error? :)

Comment: ^^ and what is the last thing printed by `Debug.Print myFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is here:
`If myFile <> "False" Then`

I guess that it should be simply like this -> `If myFile Then` or `If len(myFile) >8 Then`

---

However, the code looks working. Just try to rebuild it with Select Case, it looks way better and slightly faster:

```
Select Case strName
    Case "Macro"
        MsgBox "That's all"
        Exit Sub
    Case "TOUCHPOINTS"
        strName = "Touchpoints by markets"
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "I don't know -> "; strName
End Select
```

Probably you will find the error then.

Comment: @YowE3K - it looks like I got 1 out of 3 correct :D